# Postal Code listing in PHP/JSON/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a database of ~980k postal codes, and a form where a user can input either the Zip Code, City, State, and/or Country. I'd eventually like to create a script that auto populates the other fields based upon the results of another, but before I arrive there I'm curious what the best manner to parse that amount of data into a select box for the form. Is that not even the appropriate way? I have on code thus far, simply looking for some pseudo code or thoughts.

Database looks like this
[image]

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Jay has the right idea here. As it is this question is as broad as the sea. Narrow the question's scope and you will have better luck. Also, it is probably not a good idea to post parts of peoples address info, even if there are no names associated with it.

Comment: @jamesmatta why not? I imagine that you could fairly easily scrape this data these days

Comment: @Strawberry I am assuming this data is from some postal service database, as opposed to just the general location of an address (sans name, which is probably what UPS and similar have), While I do not know for sure it seems possible then that names are associated with the postal ID shown. It might be a bad assumption; but, as far as I am concerned anything remotely close to personal information of people other than oneself should not be posted anywhere.

Comment: the postal_code_id is only an ID that exists in my database. These have no specifics.

Comment: Use ajax to detect when the user has entered a string of three characters or more then convert the string to an integer and run a `SELECT * FROM postal_codes WHERE postal_code_id LIKE ?` and parse the results as options for the select form.  Even when you do that, still make sure you're checking if the user's input is found in the database after they submit the form.  Indexing should help you as well especially on int fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took the recommendation from [Sakamaki Izayoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4801883/sakamaki-izayoi) and found a script I modified to work with my application. Once it reaches 3 characters it searches my database of ~980k postal codes and returns the results instantly.

Let me know your guys's thoughts.

Form

```
<input type="text" id="quote_shipper_postalcode" name="quote_shipper_postalcode" class="form-control" maxlength="5">
```

Javascrpit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ac_config = {
    source: "ajax/ajax_postal_codes.php",
    select: function(event, ui){
        $("#quote_shipper_city").val(ui.item.city);
        $("#quote_shipper_state").val(ui.item.state);
        $("#quote_shipper_postalcode").val(ui.item.zip);
        $("#quote_shipper_country").val(ui.item.country);
    },
    minLength:3
};
$("#quote_shipper_postalcode").autocomplete(ac_config);
```

});

ajax script

```
<?php
include_once('../config/config.php'); 


// Cleaning up the term
    $term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

//search the database for only the first three digits to make it not such a huge query
    $zip_3 = $term;

// Rudimentary search
    $matches = array();

    foreach(list_postal_codes($db_pdo,$zip_3) as $zip){
        if(stripos($zip['zip'], $term) == false){
            $zip['value'] = $zip['zip'];
            $zip['label'] = "{$zip['zip']}, {$zip['city']} {$zip['state']} {$zip['country']}";
            $matches[] = $zip;
        } 
    } 

    if ($matches == false) { $matches[] = $zip_3 . " not found"; }


            $matches = array_slice($matches, 0, 15);
            print json_encode($matches);
```

database query

```
    function list_postal_codes($db_pdo,$zip_3) {

    //zip 3 is only the first 3 digits of the zip

    return $db_pdo->query("SELECT `postal_code_city` AS `city`,`postal_code_state` AS `state`,`postal_code_ctry` AS `country`, `postal_code_code` AS `zip` FROM `postal_codes` WHERE `postal_code_code` LIKE '" . $zip_3 . "%'");

}
```

> Blockquote